# How can I make my dictionary be able to be indexed by a function in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, indexing

I am trying to make a program that finds out how many integers in a list are not the integer that is represented the most in that list. To do that I have a command which creates a dictionary with every value in the list and the number of times it is represented in it. Next I try to create a new list with all items from the older list except the most represented value so I can count the length of the list. The problem is that I cannot access the most represented value in the dictionary as I get an error code.

```
import operator
import collections

a = [7, 155, 12, 155]
dictionary = collections.Counter(a).items()
b = []
for i in a:
    if a != dictionary[max(iter(dictionary), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]]:
        b.append(a)
```

I get this error code: TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you called `dictionary` is not a `dict` but a `dict_items`.

```
>>> type(dictionary)
<class 'dict_items'>
>>> help(dict.items)
items(...)
    D.items() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's items
```

and sets are iterable, not indexable:

```
for di in dictionary: print(di)  # is ok
dictionary[0]                    # triggers the error you saw
```

Note that Counter is very rich, maybe using `Counter.most_common` would do the trick.